# Algebraic K-theory of the cotangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

*Below, always let $A$ be the coordinate ring of a smooth affine variety over $\mathbb C$.*

What can be said about the (non)-triviality of the module of Kahler differentials $\Omega_{A/\mathbb C}^1$?

> **Question:** Is there an example of $A$ where $\Omega_{A/\mathbb C}^1$ is not free? Not stably free?

It seems like there *must* be an example of an affine variety with a non-trivial cotangent bundle, but I don't know it.

Taking a hypersurface in $\mathbb A^n$ will at best produce something stably free, and when $n=2$ it is always free, as I learned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619144/smooth-affine-plane-curve-with-non-trivial-cotangent-sheaf). Still, it would be interesting to know an example where it is non-free.

If you work over $\mathbb R$, as in Swan's [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1962-105-02/S0002-9947-1962-0143225-6/) the $n$-sphere $A = \mathbb R[x_i]/(\sum x_i^2 -1)$ has a non-trivial tangent bundle (for $n\not= 1,3,7$), but still it is stably free and becomes free when passing to $\mathbb C$.

**Update:**

I have noticed that the question about parallelizability of hypersurfaces is addressed [on overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69239/is-every-algebraic-smooth-hypersurface-of-affine-space-parallelizable).

Comment: I don't understand the significance of assuming that $A$ is a closed subvariety of an affine space. You already assumed that $A$ is affine, so...? (Also, you should probably decide whether you want $A$ to be the coordinate ring or the variety.)

Comment: If it is free, then top exterior power is free, so trivial, and the variety is Calabi-Yau. Most varieties are not Calabi-Yau!

Comment: There's a non-free example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19401/k%C3%A4hler-differentials-of-affine-varieties

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I wished the example would like like $A = \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/I$ for simplicity (as opposed to a localization of this). Also, I have seen this question you linked to, but I only see the cusp there. I really want a non-singular example so that $\Omega_A^1$ is projective.

Comment: @Ben: every affine variety is a closed subvariety of affine space. "Affine" does not mean "quasi-affine." user18119 gives a nonsingular example.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Interesting point. I am wishing for an affine variety here though, so maybe it is more likely? I'm imagining a subvariety $X \to \mathbb A^n$, and its completion in $\mathbb P^n$ isn't C-Y, but still $\omega$ is trivial on this affine piece.

Comment: There is an example there with an hyperelliptic curve

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh you're right, I don't know what I was thinking. I will take a look at user18119's answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so important for your question, but let me state it anyway. $\Omega^1_{A/k}$ is stably free if and only if it is a complete intersection in some embedding in the affine space (which in turn is equivalent to being a complete intersection in any large enough affine space). Having said that, take any smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $g\geq 2$ and take a general point $P$. Then $C-\{P\}$ is affine, but $\Omega^1$ is not free, since that is equivalent to saying $K_C=(2g-2)P$.

Comment: This is very helpful, I will think about this. Thank you again, @Mohan.